# How can I get multiple instances of GNOME Calculator at same time?

Tags: gnome, calculator, gnome-calculator

I need multiple calculators at the same time. But when I click on the calculator icon it just refers to the one that is already opened.

How can I do this in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a new terminal, then execute the following command
`gnome-calculator`

Comment: Not too practical but solve the problem. Maybe I should request it as a feature in future releases. Thanks @ducvd.

Answer (score 25):

My answer here has only been tested in Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-calculator version 3.28.0 and does not apply to older versions of Ubuntu / `gnome-calculator` which I don't have access to the app to verify.  However, in the NEWS of the source file for gnome-calculator it states:

> Overview of changes in gnome-calculator 3.23.1
>
> - Add new window appmenu entry bgo#724478 (Robert Roth)

So, my guess would be that any version newer than the version listed above the keyboard combination below should have worked fine.

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for New Window which should keep opening new instances.  If not you can follow below:

---

Once in the `gnome-calculator` app, you should be able to click the icon in the upper left corner and choose `New Window` which will open another instance of the calculator:

[image]

[image]

In the GNOME Desktop, the app menu is on the bar, but it is the same way to launch multiple calculators.  Click on Calculator in the top bar and choose `New Window`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much easier than opening the terminal and typing `gnome-calculator`.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, you should know how to run a simple terminal command anyway.

Comment: This is a decent answer, and is the only proper answer given the current state of gnome-calculator. The preferred method would be the behavior that existed in Ubuntu 16.04 where a simple shift-click on the doc icon would open a new window. This behavior is needed to facilitate opening a calculator in the current workspace.

Answer (score 4):

It seems it's an intentional implementation by the developers. Almost all other applications provide an option to open a new window in the context menu (right-click menu) in Ubuntu dock while an instance is running and you can assign this option to mouse-middle-click, but Calculator application in particular doesn't provide the option at all!

[image]

As a hacky workaround you may try the following.

1. Copy the launcher for Calculator (probably named `org.gnome.Calculator.desktop`) from `/usr/share/applications/` and paste to `~/.local/share/applications/`.
2. Open the copied file using a text editor.
3. Look for a line beginning with `Actions=`. If there is one, append `new-instance;` to it. Otherwise add the following line

   ```
   Actions=new-instance;
   ```
4. Append the following lines to the end of the file and save it.

   ```
   [Desktop Action new-instance]
   Name=New instance
   Exec=gnome-calculator
   ```
5. Re-login just to be sure.

Now when you have Calculator running, if you right click on its icon in the dock, you should see a "*New instance*" option.

[image]

Click on the *New instance* option, it should launch another Calculator.

[image]

Comment: Middle-click does not work but apart from that, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>super</kbd> key (to bring up the Activities overview), start typing in the name of the application you want until it is selected, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will work for any application, including a version of `gnome-calculator` which does not have a "New Window" option (like mine: v3.22.3-1).

Comment: It seems this doesn't work with the calculator application (both snap and apt versions) on Ubuntu 18.04, but works on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (v3.18).

Comment: @pomsky: interesting.  I wonder whether that is a GNOME change or something Ubuntu have patched in.

Comment: It's a change to gnome-calculator.  See my answer.

Comment: Still works for me with gnome-calculator 3.30.1 in Debian.  If it does not work in Ubuntu, it might just be an Ubuntu patch.